# "NSCFBoolean objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" in React Native

Tags: react-native, exception, compiler-errors, expo, use-state

I am using React Native with Expo and this was originally a class based component but I converted it to a functional component because I want to use hooks. Now it is throwing an error shown in the screenshot. I am not sure what to do about the error?I have seen one other posting about this, but was a little lost (I am practicing with react). The component is basically a GPS with a marker! Thank you

[image]

```
import { View, Text, Animated, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "react-native-vector-icons";
```

```
const LATITUDE = 18.7934829;
const LONGITUDE = 98.9867401;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.009;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.009;

export default function MapLocation() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    isLoading: true,
    latitude: LATITUDE,
    longitude: LONGITUDE,
    error: null,
  });

  var getMapRegion = () => ({
    latitude: location.latitude,
    longitude: location.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  });

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      console.log(position);
      setLocation({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        error: null,
      });
    },
    (error) => setLocation({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );

  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    setLocation({ latitude, longitude });
  });

  const { isLoading } = location;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        region={getMapRegion}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
      >
        <Marker coordinate={getMapRegion}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="egg" color={"white"} size={35} style={styles.shadow} />
        </Marker>

        <Marker
          coordinate={{ latitude: 34.0198536, longitude: -80.923467 }}
          pinColor="maroon"
          title={"title"}
          description={"description"}
        >
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="school" color={"maroon"} size={40} style={styles.shadow} />
        </Marker>
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadow: {
    // transform: [{ rotateZ: "10deg" }],
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 3,
  },
});
```

Comment: I notice  with "const { isLoading } = location;"  loading is never read. not sure if related.

Comment: Also I should be using a useEffect probably.

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems with my conversion to hooks using useState and useEffect. Both of which I solved with this guide on converting classes to functions. I was not using the "useEffect hook" in place of component did mount, I also did not have an empty array at the end of the useEffect hook which made it re-render constantly from what I understand.

[Link to functional component conversion steps](https://olinations.medium.com/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139)